# Python Dict: Get value associated with with a list of keys, where each subsequent key resides in the previous key's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here is a better explanation,
I have a list of keys of a dict:

```
keys_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

and my dict is:

```py
my_dict = {'one':{'two': {'three': 'three_value'}, 'some': 'some_value'}, 'next': 'next_value'}
```

I would actually like my code to traverse through the list to get the value associated with the last key, as such

```py
print(my_dict['one']['two']['three'])
# Output: three_value
```

If the keys_list changed to:

```py
keys_list = ['next']
```

It would search

```py
print(my_dict['next'])
# Output: next_value
```

#### My current solution

```py
import copy
copied_dict = copy.deepcopy(my_dict)
for key in keys_list:
    copied_dict = copied_dict[key]
print(copied_dict)
```

It is bad, I know and would love a simpler solution.

Comment: Have `result = my_dict` and then `for key in keys_list: result = result[key]`